# Sort array by score values in another array with same keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays like this:

Array (key is ID user, value is name) #1

```
[7] => "John Doe"
[12] => "Steve Jobs"
[20] => "Brad Pitt"
```

Array (key is ID user, value is score for sorting) #2

```
[7] => 45
[12] => 27
[20] => 50.5
```

Expected result after sorting (lowest value first, highest last)

```
[12] => "Steve Jobs"
[7] => "John Doe"
[20] => "Brad Pitt"
```

What is easiest way to achiev that? Thanks

Comment: Please make your question more clear. What does Array 2 have to do with it?

Comment: It is score for sorting, lowest value first, Highest last.

Comment: @Blackbam Array2 is the condition of sorting array1

Comment: I think it's clear enough.. First array contains names, Second array contains Score, so he wants to sort names by score, but he has it in 2 arrays .. don't know why it's downvoted so many times

Comment: Edited, now it should be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
asort($arr2);
$finalArr=[];
foreach($arr2 as $key => $value){
  $finalArr[$key]=$arr1[$key];
}
```

We are doing sorting and maintaining the index association ([asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php))

We are looping the sorted array and comparing with the first array and storing to the final array

Comment: check your foreach loop, you're missing something ;)

Comment: @moped fixed foreach

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of doing what you want is using [asort](http://php.net/asort) to sort the array and the [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/array_replace_recursive) to merge the values. ([Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/886192b898d26984724110a07ee14e874e50f00a))

```
<?php

    $a = [
        7  => "John Doe",
        12 => "Steve Jobs",
        20 => "Brad Pitt"
    ];

    $b = [
        7  => 45,
        12 => 27,
        20 => 50.5
    ];

    asort($b);
    $result = array_replace_recursive($b,$a);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd recommend you to do is:
create array with associative array in it, because that would be way more readable

```
$people = [
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'score' => 45],
    ['name' => 'Steve Jobs', 'score' => 27],
    ['name' => 'Brad Pitt', 'score' => 50.5],
]
```

And sorting with usort() - something like this:

```
function sortScores($a, $b) {
    return ($a['score'] - $b['score']);
}

usort($people, 'sortScores');
```

This is more like an advice btw

Edit:

for select:

```
foreach ($people as $p) {
    echo $p['name']
}
```

it's as simple as that, just add tags to your echo or however you are printing that

Comment: I need to use that array as select's options, so Dhayal's solution is better for my case. But thanks anyway...

Comment: @AdamVýborný There's no problem for that with this

Comment: I use Nette Forms in Nette Framework. You have to specify options by a array, where key is value and value is label.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php

$names[7] = "John Doe";
$names[12] = "Steve Jobs";
$names[20] = "Brad Pitt";

$ages[7] = 45;
$ages[12] = 27;
$ages[20] = 50.5;

// Sort second array on age values
asort($ages);

// Loop through sorted age array
foreach($ages as $key => $value) {

  // Get name and insert into new array
  $sortedArray[$key] = $names[$key];
}

// Print sorted names
print_r($sortedArray);
?>
```